# what is wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: bash

The following piece of code where I want to check if an array is empty gives the error - `re.sh: line 3: [0: command not found`. The error is at the if statement. What is wrong with it?

```
#!/bin/bash
unique_hero=()
if [${#unique_hero[@]} -eq 0]
 then unique_hero+=('asdf')
 echo "${unique_hero[@]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is correct, but remember to use the spaces before and after the brackets

```
#!/bin/bash
unique_hero=()
if [ ${#unique_hero[@]} -eq 0 ]
   then unique_hero+=('asdf')
echo "${unique_hero[@]}"
fi
```