# shell script to remove files didn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to delete multiple images having resolution less then 228x228.
For that, I wrote this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( ls ); do
    if [$(identify -format "%w" $i) < 228] && [$(identify -format "%h" $i) < 228];
    then
        rm $i
    fi
done
```

For some reasons, I got this output when I run it:

```
./del.sh: line 4: [640: command not found
./del.sh: line 4: [550: command not found
./del.sh: line 4: [315: command not found
...
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong in this script and how to fix it.
Thank you.

**EDIT:** Even after I added spaces after the brackets, I still got an error. It was due to the usage of `<` instead of `-lt` and has been fixed. Now there is no error.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/246819)

Comment: You need spaces after `[` and before `]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is wrong with this piece of code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448257/what-is-wrong-with-this-piece-of-code)

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks? I only showed up because this was in Hot Questions, don't expect me to show up regularly.

Comment: Please never use the output of `$( ls )` in a script, because `ls` doesn't have a universal standard. It's anyway more readable and more efficient in the loop to use `for i in *; do`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some issues here: Firstly, the expression in a `[…]` test needs spaces around it ([pitfall #10](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_...)), and secondly
the comparison `<` doesn't work with `[…]` tests ([pitfall #7](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B.5B_.24foo_.3E_7_.5D.5D)). You either need `-lt` (*less than*)
or use `[[…]]` instead, which is a *bashism*. Also, the `for` loop should be replaced ([pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)).

So:

```
for i in ./*; do
    if [ -e "$i" ]; then
        if [ $(identify -format "%w" "$i") -lt 228 ] && [ $(identify -format "%h" "$i") -lt 228 ];
        then
            rm -- "$i"
        fi
    fi
done
```

You may also want to avoid calling `identify` twice to get the two dimensions ([pitfall #58](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#month.3D.24.28date_.2B-.25m.29.3B_day.3D.24.28date_.2B-.25d.29)) but call
it just once instead and let it print a string ready to be used as variable assignments in shell syntax.

If we write

```
identify -format "width=%w height=%h" "$i"
```

it will print something like `width=50 heigth=250`. When we `eval`uate that string then we have set two variables with just one call and the condition can be written as:

```
eval "$(identify -format "width=%w height=%h" "$i")"
if [ $width -lt 228 ] && [ $height -lt 228 ];
then
    rm -- "$i"
fi
```

See also: [common bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a loop, I'd use `find` with `-exec` and `-delete`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  \
   -exec sh -c '
       [ $(identify -format "%w" "$1") -lt 228 ] &&
       [ $(identify -format "%h" "$1") -lt 228 ]' _ {} \; \
   -delete -print
```

This will also print the files that get deleted, you can remove `-print` if you don't want that.

Comment: "This will also print the files that get deleted, you can remove -print if you don't want that." Or remove the `-delete` and run it once as a dry run to sanity check before restoring it and running for real.

Answer (score 3):

Not intended to answer but to give a useful tip that helped me much doing bash scripting.

There's a shell script linter called `shellcheck` that might trap some common errors in bash scripts and also avoid some pitfalls. It can be installed like any package in ubuntu -> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shellcheck is in `universe` for current stable.

This is the output for your script

```
shellcheck del.sh

In del.sh line 4:
    if [$(identify -format "%w" $i) < 228] && [$(identify -format "%h" $i) < 228];
    ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
       ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
        ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
                                          ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ].
                                          ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

If you fix and apply again you'll get some other recommendations and fixes already mentioned in the accepted answer.